# Make a new column in a dataframe for every new instance based off another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to make new columns in a dataframe based on how many times a new value gets paired with another column.

original dataframe:

| Name | Primary Address | Alternative Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | 123 Fudge Rd. | UHP.INC |
| Lee Smith | Pro Sports,LLC |  |
| Hank Hill | Pharm Tank.co | PodRacing.Cool |
| Hank Hill |  | GhoulSchool,343 |
| Hank Hill |  | MoneyTree Rd. |

Dataframe Im trying to achieve where if there is multiple alternative addresses to one name they split out to as many columns as needed:

| Name | Primary Address | Alternative Address | Alternative Address_2 | Alternative Address_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | 123 Fudge Rd. | UHP.INC |  |  |
| Lee Smith | Pro Sports,LLC |  |  |  |
| Hank Hill | Pharm Tank.co | PodRacing.Cool | GhoulSchool,343 | MoneyTree Rd. |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe it'll be more convenient for you to have such columns: "Primary address" and "Alternative Address**es**" which contains all the alternative addresses in a **list** for each person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a column that contains a **list of all "alternative addresses"** for each person:

```py
f = lambda g: pd.Series([g['Primary'].dropna().iloc[0],
                         list(g['Alternative'].dropna())], 
                        index=['Primary', 'Alternative'])

new_df = df.groupby('Name').apply(f).reset_index()
```

If you need, you can then [**split this column into new columns**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/split-a-pandas-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns):

```py
alt_addresses = (pd.DataFrame(new_df['Alternative'].tolist())
                 .add_prefix('Alternative_Address_'))
result = pd.concat([new_df.drop(columns='Alternative'), alt_addresses], axis=1)
```

---

**Results:**

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Name': ['John Doe', 'Lee Smith', 'Hank Hill', 'Hank Hill', 'Hank Hill'], 
     'Primary': ['123 Fudge Rd.', 'Pro Sports,LLC', 'Pharm Tank.co', np.nan, np.nan], 
     'Alternative': ['UHP.INC', None, 'PodRacing.Cool', 'GhoulSchool,343', 'MoneyTree Rd.']})
```

```py
print(new_df)

        Name         Primary                                       Alternative
0  Hank Hill   Pharm Tank.co  [PodRacing.Cool, GhoulSchool,343, MoneyTree Rd.]
1   John Doe   123 Fudge Rd.                                         [UHP.INC]
2  Lee Smith  Pro Sports,LLC                                                []
```

```py
print(result)

        Name         Primary  Alternative_Address_0  Alternative_Address_1  Alternative_Address_2
0  Hank Hill   Pharm Tank.co         PodRacing.Cool        GhoulSchool,343          MoneyTree Rd.
1   John Doe   123 Fudge Rd.                UHP.INC                   None                   None   
2  Lee Smith  Pro Sports,LLC                   None                   None                   None
```